# Cannot use object of type classname as array error

Tags: php

Here is the situation, I'm trying to insert data in a for loop using a model, however, I keep getting an Cannot use object of type App_Model_TogaDesk_RepairOrderFiles as array error.

Here is the code:

```
    for ($i=0; $i < $countfiles; $i++) {
      $fileNameAct = $files['file']['name'][$i];
      $type = $files['file']['type'][$i];
      $tmp_name = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
      $size = $files['file']['size'][$i];
      $error = $files['file']['error'][$i];
 
      $files = new App_Model_TogaDesk_RepairOrderFiles();
      $files->workorderid = $repairid;
      $files->RevUserFileName = $fileNameAct;
      $files->RevUserFileType = $type;
      $files->RevServerFilePath = $filePath;
      $files->currentVersion = '1';
      $files->personid = $data['personid'];
      $versionid = $files->save();
   }
```

Even though the data is actually an array, for some reason, it thinks it is an object.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($data);`, that will show you what type it _actually_ is.

Comment: Scratch that, the message is not even about $data … You start with $files apparently being an array, but then you _overwrite_ that variable with `$files = new App_Model_TogaDesk_RepairOrderFiles();` - so on the next loop iteration, it will of course not be an array any more, and your attempts to access `$files['file']['name'][$i];` must therefor fail …

Comment: The error message should have told you which line of the script this is referring to, so pay a bit of attention to that next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue, what happened, I had the array named as the model call.

So I changed the model from

```
  $files = new App_Model_TogaDesk_RepairOrderFiles();
```

to

```
 $file = new App_Model_TogaDesk_RepairOrderFiles();
```

That did the trick.